# Joomla crash after installation

Tags: php, windows, apache, joomla

`http://localhost/joomla/administrator/` The web browser returns an error that the page does not exist after I complete the installation and deleted the folder.

I have to use apache2. I am also using the latest version of apache, mysql. Im using php 5.2.13 VC6 x86 Thread Safe.

I used a combo of two tutorials:

[Tutorial 1](http://autoindex.sourceforge.net/forum/apache.php?id=0)
[Tutorial 2](http://www.scribd.com/doc/11197649/Installation-of-Joomla-on-Windows-XP-using-Apache-Mysql-and-PHP)

When I chose `mysql` as the database it would give me the error right away but if I chose `mysqli` then I would be able to complete the installation then when I selected either client or administrator then I would get the browser error.

The only difference between the two tutorials is that I used `PHPIniDir` instead of copying and pasting it to apache.

httpd.conf

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/datafiles/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml .inc .php3 
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
PHPIniDir "c:/datafiles/php"
```

I also changed `ServerName localhost:80` due to an error in the log.

error.log

```
[Fri Jul 09 07:05:21 2010] [notice] Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Fri Jul 09 07:05:21 2010] [notice] Child 4108: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Fri Jul 09 07:05:22 2010] [notice] Child 4108: Released the start mutex
[Fri Jul 09 07:05:23 2010] [notice] Child 4108: All worker threads have exited.
[Fri Jul 09 07:05:23 2010] [notice] Child 4108: Child process is exiting
[Fri Jul 09 07:05:23 2010] [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully.
[Fri Jul 09 07:06:23 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Win32) PHP/5.2.13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jul 09 07:06:23 2010] [notice] Server built: Mar  4 2010 11:27:46
[Fri Jul 09 07:06:23 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3520
[Fri Jul 09 07:06:23 2010] [notice] Child 3520: Child process is running
[Fri Jul 09 07:06:23 2010] [notice] Child 3520: Acquired the start mutex.
[Fri Jul 09 07:06:23 2010] [notice] Child 3520: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Fri Jul 09 07:06:23 2010] [notice] Child 3520: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Fri Jul 09 07:08:00 2010] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Fri Jul 09 07:08:00 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Win32) PHP/5.2.13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jul 09 07:08:00 2010] [notice] Server built: Mar  4 2010 11:27:46
[Fri Jul 09 07:08:00 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 6584
[Fri Jul 09 07:08:00 2010] [notice] Child 6584: Child process is running
[Fri Jul 09 07:08:00 2010] [notice] Child 6584: Acquired the start mutex.
[Fri Jul 09 07:08:00 2010] [notice] Child 6584: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Fri Jul 09 07:08:00 2010] [notice] Child 6584: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Fri Jul 09 07:08:01 2010] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Fri Jul 09 07:08:01 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Win32) PHP/5.2.13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jul 09 07:08:01 2010] [notice] Server built: Mar  4 2010 11:27:46
[Fri Jul 09 07:08:01 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 5780
[Fri Jul 09 07:08:01 2010] [notice] Child 5780: Child process is running
[Fri Jul 09 07:08:02 2010] [notice] Child 5780: Acquired the start mutex.
[Fri Jul 09 07:08:02 2010] [notice] Child 5780: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Fri Jul 09 07:08:02 2010] [notice] Child 5780: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

All pre-installation checks are perfect.

I even tried the PHP installers from the two currently available version but they don't let me start apache.

edit: It was able to install with mysqli the data samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Disabling each extension in php.ini file to see which extension is causing the crash .most of the time the "Curl Extension" would be the reason for the Crash.

Comment: This was probably the problem with my setup but I found a much more comprehensive tutorial and it now works!